# How can I run cypress test in parallel inside GitLab runner? (Without using cypress dashboard)

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

I've created around 180 end-to-end tests around a web application. Now I can't afford to run those sequentially. I've tried running it in parallel via the cypress dashboard. But they provide only 500 test runs per month and then it doesn't work in parallel. In my git lab runner, I am seeing this error:

[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I run tests in parallel with cypress and GitLab only?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do some hackings/workarounds hahaha but will work.

First you need to have in your root path the file `.gitlab-ci.yml`. In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` define how many parallel jobs do you want, in my case I will use as example two parallel jobs to run the same tests in different browsers(chrome and firefox):

```
stages: 
  - triggers

smoke-test-chrome:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: gitlab-ci/smoke-test-chrome/.gitlab-ci.yml

smoke-test-firefox:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: gitlab-ci/smoke-test-firefox/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Now you need to create the `.gitlab-ci.yml` for each parallel job in different directories but all included in a main directory called `gitlab-ci/`

In my example I will create two files with the following path:

- `gitlab-ci/smoke-test-chrome/.gitlab-ci.yml`
- `gitlab-ci/smoke-test-firefox/.gitlab-ci.yml`

In the `gitlab-ci/smoke-test-chrome/.gitlab-ci.yml` file I will have:

```
stages:
  - triggers

smoke-test-chrome:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
  stage: triggers
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run smoke:test-chrome
```

And in the `gitlab-ci/smoke-test-firefox/.gitlab-ci.yml` file I will have:

```
stages:
  - triggers

smoke-test-firefox:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
  stage: triggers
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run smoke:test-firefox
```

Last create your specific scripts in your `package.json`, in my example I created:

```
"smoke:test-chrome": "cypress run --browser chrome --spec 'cypress/integration/Signup/SmokeTests.test.ts'",
"smoke:test-firefox": "cypress run --browser firefox --spec 'cypress/integration/Signup/SmokeTests.test.ts'",
```

In your case, you can just change the spec files you want to called in each specific job by changing those specs in `package.json` script and calling those scripts in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files you have created before